# Better performance method than Django templates?

Tags: django

I have complete header, body, and footer files. What would be the fastest way to send them to the client in order? I assume reading them to HttpResponse or some other method would be faster than sending through the template tools.

Looked all over the internet for best way and through some of the docs, now I come to you ... Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are "complete header, body, and footer files"? Are they always the same, or how many different combinations are there? I'm thinking of just concatenating them and having them by served by a good web server like Nginx.

Comment: I use Django as UI for users to change content and I store it in MongoDB. I have the header data, each page data, and the footer data output as static files separately so when they make some tiny change to the header or footer every page doesn't have to be rewritten.

Ultimately, the static pages serve much faster than the database hit of course, but I assume there is a better method than sending it all through the render process.

Comment: I would worry less about rendering performance and more about caching. If the pages are more or less static, proper caching will be the fastest way to serve those pages, regardless of how fast they render.

Comment: OK, thanks. I am moving 20 clients over to python/django from C# (because the development will be faster overall) and they will all be on the same server (as all the clients are now). I will look at caching performance.